# Add line separator after action bar in android API 21 and newer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

So I want to add a divider/separator at the bottom of the action bar in android, I have achieved this in pre lollipop Api's using windowContentOverlay like this

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/line</item>
```

and this is the drawable line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:height="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

and this is the graphical output that I have achieved and want in the newer android versions

[image]
I have tried to create a view of width 1dp and adding it to the activity xml but and removing the shadow, but this is not practical because It would require me to do this in all the views that uses the action bar.

This is my output in lollipop right now, this gives me a shadow, and if I remove it, the line separator wont appear.

[image]

how can I achieve the same look as in pre lollipop?

Comment: add View in the layout......  <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp"
             android:background="Add-Your_Color"/>

Comment: @WaqarYounis I already tried that but it's not practical because I have more than one activity layout that needs this line, so it's not good to write the same thing in each activity